# Problemas com o mobile Max Mega Menu WordPress

Tags: wordpress, mobile, menu

Fala pessoal,
Recentemente eu instalei o plugin Max Mega Menu no site do meu cliente e deixei tudo ajeitado e fluindo bem na versão de desktop funcionando direitinho. Quando fui ver no mobile o menu responsivo desse plugin não está funcionando.
Queria saber se alguém tem alguma ideia do que possa está impedindo o funcionamento?

Comment: Isso é algo complicado de responder, existem muitas possibilidades de problemas. O que torna sua pergunta ampla demais. Minha dica é, o menos sempre é mais. Tente desenvolver um menu simples que abre na lateral com Jquery Mobile. Veja como é simples: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.2/panel/

Comment: Boa ideia tava pensando em fazer algo fora do plugin mesmo...Vlw pelo link man